# Style won't apply to child element in sass

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, jsx

I have a child element that is rendering with a simple string custom class passed from a variable. Since it's a variable and will change, I want to write conditional styles in scss. Example shown when variable is 'poor' -> `current.range.total = 'poor'`.

```
<div className={styles.score__content}>
   <div className={current.range.total}>
```

My scss is:

```
&__content {
  .poor {
    padding: 2em 2.81em;
    background-color: #000 !important;
  }
}
```

I've also tried:

```
<div className={styles.score__content + ' ' + current.range.total}>
```

And then scss:

```
&__content {
  &.poor {
    padding: 2em 2.81em;
    background-color: #000;
  }
}
```

But to no avail. Any ideas why the styles aren't being applied?

Comment: Do your classes apply correctly to those `<div />`'s? How do you include your `.scss` into the app? Also why `&` sign before `__content`?

Comment: What does `styles.score__content` process out to as a string? I agree with @GProst, the `&__content` doesn't look right and that's probably why your styles aren't getting applied.